# Allow only one user to run/access app/program

Tags: permissions, vpn

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
2 users assigned

My desktop is set up with two user accounts.  One for personal and one for work.  I want to keep those tasks separate.

I have a vpn that is used for work. Globalprotect.

It seems to have conflicts between the two users.  I only want one account to have access to the VPN.

I want to restrict access to the VPN to one user account only.

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from *not* using the VPN when logged in with said user?

Comment: The vpn service starts when either user is logged in.  It seems as though there is conflict and then i have issues getting the UI to open up.  If there is only one user logged in then there are no problems

Comment: For startup applications, you can disable these on a per-account basis. Load the tool "Startup Applications". Chances are you can disable there. Please update the title of your question to hint this is related to autostarting upon login.

Comment: @vanadium.  Thank you. I already removed the VPN app from the start up applications folder.